# Ejecutar doble click, solo con un click

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Funcionalidad]

Como puedo hacer que al dar click en el boton +, automáticamente vuelva a ejecutar la misma funcionalidad pero como si hubiera dado click en el otro boton del +.

lo necesito asi ya que uno trae unos datos diferente al otro, pero quiero que sea automatizado, que entienda que cuando al del lado izquierdo le den click el tambien se ejecute.

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que agregaras el codigo que estas usando, para asi poder ayudarte mas facilmente

Comment: es bastante extenso la funcionalidad ya la tengo, solo quiero que al dar click en un boton el otro entienda que el tambien se debe presionar y ejecutar la logica que tengo.

Comment: Coloca todo el código del evento `onclick` en una nueva función, por ejemplo: `function sumar()` y luego en tu código, dentro del evento `onclick` llama dos veces al nuevo método. Ejemplo: `myButton_click() { sumar(); sumar();}`..

Comment: Si lo que quieres hacer es que, cuando se haga click en el botón + de la izquierda o derecha, programáticamente se haga click en el otro botón +, lo puedes hacer simplemente mediante: `otroBoton.click()`.

Comment: la funcionalidad no deberia ser dependiente de la vista, deberia ser al reves.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes hacer es hacer **trigger** del evento click en el otro botón **+**.

Desconozco si necesitas hacer que cada botón reaccione en consecuencia del otro. En ese caso debes verificar si el evento **click** ha sido lanzado por una acción del usuario o por ti por medio del código. En el caso de haber sido lanzado el evento del código no lanzarías el **click** sobre el otro botón o generarías una reacción infinita.

```js
$(function () {
  var $btnIncA = $('#btn-inc-a');
  var $btnIncB = $('#btn-inc-b');
  var $inputA = $('#input-a');
  var $inputB = $('#input-b');

  $btnIncA.on('click', function (e) {
    $inputA.val(parseInt($inputA.val()) + 1);

    // Verificamos si el evento fue lanzado por una acción del usuario o desde el otro botón. O se seguirían incrementando el uno al otro hasta el infinito o más allá
    if (e.originalEvent) {
      $btnIncB.trigger('click');
    }
  });

  $btnIncB.on('click', function (e) {
    $inputB.val(parseInt($inputB.val()) + 1);

    // Verificamos si el evento fue lanzado por una acción del usuario o desde el otro botón. O se seguirían incrementando el uno al otro hasta el infinito o más allá
    if (e.originalEvent) {
      $btnIncA.trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-inc-a">Incrementar A</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-inc-b">Incrementar B</button>
  <input type="text" id="input-a" value="1">
  <input type="text" id="input-b" value="1">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Suerte y Saludos!

Comment: lo que necesito es que al yo presionar el boton icrementarA, despues de que se ejecute la lógica de ese incrementar A, se de click en incrementar B. porque en mi caso cada input tiene unos atributos definidos para interactuar con ellos desde javascript. entonces por obligación tengo que hacerlo. como te indico me comprendes?

Comment: @KmiiloBerrioMontoya Hola! ... Es exactamente lo que hace el código. Si te fijas `$btnIncB.trigger('click');` lo que hace es hacer **click** desde el código en el botón **Incrementar B**. Que ejecuta su propio código correspondiente. Saludos!